# TYPE ERROR: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, json, geolocation

import folium
nyc_neighborhoods_geojson = "file:///C:/Users/ahmed/Downloads/zip_code_040114.geojson"
m = folium.Map(location=(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom_start=3, tiles="cartodb positron")

```
    # Assuming 'ZIP CODE' is the key for ZIP code in your data
   df = df.dropna(subset=['ZIP CODE', 'CONTRIBUTING FACTOR VEHICLE 1'])

     # Group by ZIP CODE and find the most common contributing factor for each group
     zip_code_data = df.groupby('ZIP CODE')['CONTRIBUTING FACTOR VEHICLE 1'].agg(lambda x:                               
     x.mode().iat[0]).reset_index()
    # Use 'feature.properties.ZIPCODE' as the key for ZIP code
    folium.Choropleth(
     geo_data=nyc_neighborhoods_geojson, 
     data=zip_code_data,
     columns=['ZIP CODE', 'CONTRIBUTING FACTOR VEHICLE 1'],
     key_on="feature.properties.ZIPCODE",
 ).add_to(m)

   m.save("footprint.html")`
```

Comment: Please edit your question to format the code correctly, and please spell out what your question is.